# passing php data/variable to a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some data being created(generated from database) using a while loop. Each set of data carries some form of id and its corresponding button is added to it. Now, when I click a button, I'd like to pass the id(single php variable) of the data related to this button to a modal window(that has a form) that pops and also make it the value of an input field. Here's my code so far:

**The data from database:**

```
<?php while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_set)) { ?>
<div class="w3-section w3-row w3-card-2">
  <div class="w3-half">
    <div class="apartment-image w3-card-4">
      <header class="w3-container">
        <h4><?php echo $data['data_name']; ?></h4>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="<?php echo "images/".$data['Image1']; ?>" class="w3-image" alt="<?php echo $data['dataimgname']; ?>">
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-contanier w3-border-top">
        <div class="w3-border-right">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-btn-block" type="button" name="btnBook" id="modalOpener" onclick="document.getElementById('book').style.display='block';">
            Book or Request Tour
          </button>
        </div>
```

**The Modal:**

```
<div id="book" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content">
  <header class="w3-container">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('book').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">
      &times;
    </span>
    <h2>Book or Request Tour</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <form class="w3-form" action="bookntour-handler.php" method="post">
      <div class="w3-group">
        <label class="w3-label" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
        <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="fullname" value="">
      </div>
      <label class="w3-label" for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <input class="w3-input" type="email" name="email" value="">
      <label class="w3-label" for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
      <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="telephone" value="">
      <label class="w3-label" for="dataname">Data Name:</label>
      <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="dataname" value="">
      <div class="w3-group">
        <input class="w3-btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Like I said earlier, I want to pass the id associated with the button but from my code there is nothing that mentions about "id" so let's use.

```
<?php echo $data["data_name"]; ?>
```

When I open the modal window, I'd like this variable to be made as the value for input:

```html
<label class="w3-label" for="dataname">Data Name:</label>
          <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="dataname" value="">
```

I have looked at a couple of options so far but most of them seem unnecessary in my case or I simply don't understand them. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431344/how-to-pass-php-variable-to-modal-window) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259670/passing-php-variable-to-bootstrap-modal) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438060/trouble-passing-php-variable-to-modal-window). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693863/pass-php-variable-to-bootstrap-modal) seems like a workable solution but it requires me to fetch the whole data again, from the database(using AJAX) which I do not want. I just want that one value.

I am using [W3CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp) for my layouts and creating the modal. A solution in jQuery/JavaScript or PHP(or both) will be appreciated. Thank you!

---

### Update

So, I somehow managed to solve part of the problem. I added this function to my external JavaScript file:

```js
function showModal() {
  document.forms["bookntourForm"]["apartmentno"].value = document.getElementsByClassName("modalOpener")[0].getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById('book').style.display='block';
}
```

Then the code for the button that calls the above function looks like this:

```html
<button class="w3-btn w3-btn-block modalOpener" type="button" name="btnBook" onclick="showModal()" value="<?php echo $data['data_name']; ?>">
                Book or Request Tour
              </button>
```

This brings up a new problem. Whenever I open the modal, the value for `<input class="w3-input" type="text" name="dataname" value="">` on the modal is the same for all modals although they are different when each button is generated.

Comment: Although doing this may pose security problems, one way is to pass the ID as a GET, then let the modal check if there is a value for that GET

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your id through ajax to the backend and retrieve necessary data regarding that ID by using a query,
Then set values to the necessary place inside the success method.
As you say, I don't think as a good suggestion to use data_name instead of id.
you can set your id in hidden field and use it. because "data_name" will not be good solution to retrieve data by unique field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have done this in a proper manner, but it was as simple as this. I changed the value of onclick attribute of the button to:

```html
      <button class="w3-btn w3-btn-block modalOpener" type="button" name="btnBook" onclick="showModal('<?php echo $apartment["ApartmentNo"]; ?>')">
                Book or Request Tour
              </button>
```

The showModal() function in the external JS now looks like this:

```js
var aptNo;
function showModal(aptNo) {
  document.forms["bookntourForm"]["apartmentno"].value = aptNo;
  document.getElementById('book').style.display='block';
}
```

It now works the way I wanted.